# Transformation matrix from 2 groups of point pairs

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-cvst, least-squares, matrix-transform

I have tried using the command `estimateGeometricTransform` or `fitgeotrans` but it returns an object of class `affine2d`, and what I need is to generate a transformation matrix that can plot.

Is there any specific command?

Comment: Who are they? Please show some code and perhaps add context and explain better what you want to do. Thanks!

Comment: I edited, it is difficult to explain because I still do not understand well what to do. @Benoit_11

Comment: Can't you ask *them* to explain further? Is counter-intuitive to ask explanations from the ones that don't know the problem, while *not* asking for explanations from the ones that know the problem.

Comment: I edited, now asking something more specific. @CST-Link

Answer (score 0):

The `affine2d` class has a property `T`, which contains the transformation matrix.

```
tform = estimateGeometricTransform(...)
tform.T % prints the transformation matrix
```